# Auto-rollback the changes if terraform job failed between execution step

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Working with one .tf file which include creation of s3 bucket,ec2 and security group, my concern is that if i ran terraform apply and it successfully created s3 bucket after that abort in between .
In above case i wanted to rollback the all changes happened after terraform apply ran.

Once .tf file started running ,i had abort the process but changes won't rollback.

```
provider "aws" { }
resource "aws_instance" "example" {
    ami  = "ami-2757f631"
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
}
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "b" {
    bucket = "my-tf-test-bucket"
    acl = "private"
    tags = {
        Name = "My bucket"
        Environment = "Dev"
    }
}
resource "aws_security_group" "allow_rdp" {
    name = "allow_rdp"
    description = "Allow rdp traffic"
    ingress {
    from_port = 3389 #  By default, the windows server listens on TCP port 3389 for RDP
    to_port = 3389
    protocol = "tcp" 
}
}
```

Comment: Terraform expressly won't rollback changes in the event of an exit midway through or if it fails. If you want to do that you need to be directly involved or build some form of system that will do it for you (eg revert the change in source code and reapply). Normally thought you'd want a human involved in the loop here to work out what needs to be done because this should never really happen outside of development.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR  can we maintain versions of state file and for rollback perform below steps: 1. take difference of last 2 recent state file 2. rollback only changes coming from step1.

Comment: The state file just tells Terraform what it has created. Rolling back the state file isn't what you want to do here because that would tell Terraform it didn't create the S3 bucket yet when it had. Instead you'd want to roll back the Terraform code and reapply against latest state so that it knows that it previously created the S3 bucket but is no longer wanted to Terraform will generate a plan to remove the S3 bucket, rolling back the actual change you made.